# What's different between "$myvariable =" and Set-Variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, variable-assignment

When I study PowerShell scripting language, I try to use "Write-Output" command to display variable.

I use a different method to create variables.

Example:

`$myvariable = 0x5555`

`Set-Variable -Name myvariable2 -Value 0x5555`

The data type of these two variables is Int32.

When I use the command as below,

`Write-Output $myvariable $myvariable2`

the result is `21845` and `0x5555`.

What's different between these two variables?

How can I display format result like `printf %d %x`?

Comment: `$myvariable2` is not `Int32`. It is `PSObject` which wrap `Int32` value but preserve original string representation. `[Type]::GetTypeArray(($myvariable, $myvariable2))`

Comment: Tagging on to PetSerAI --- and $myvariable is the result of the hex 0x5555 being coerced to a decimal. If you type just that hex without the assignment in the console, you'll get the same result.

Comment: I am confused about the data type. When I use `$myvariable.GetType()` and `$myvariable2.GetType()`, the results are `Int32`. But when I use `[Type]::GetTypeArray(($myvariable, $myvariable2))`, `$myvariable2` is `PSObject`.
How can I display format result like `printf %d %x` or `fprintf %d %x` to file?

Comment: `"{0:d} 0x{0:x}\`n{1:d} 0x{1:x}" -f $myvariable,$myvariable2|out-file .\test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**:

- The answer to the *general* question in the post's *title* is:
  `$var = $value` is *typically* the same as `Set-Variable var $value`
  (`Set-Variable -Name var -Value $value`)

  - [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) has additional parameters, which provide functionality that *direct assignment* using `=`, the [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators), cannot.
  - Unless you need these parameters, there's **usually *no* good reason to use `Set-Variable`** - direct assignment is more concise, performs better, and avoids surprises.
- As the code in the question's body shows, this is *not always* the case, and such *edge cases* are explained below.

  - The **tl;dr** of avoiding the problem is:

    - **If you *must* use `Set-Variable`, enclose the `-Value` argument in `(...)`**:
      `Set-Variable -Name myvariable2 -Value (0x5555)`
    - This ensures that the value is a regular, non-`[psobject]`-wrapped `[int]` ([`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32)) instance, which PowerShell's output formatting renders in *decimal* format *by default*.
- As an *aside*: If your intent is to control a number's string representation *explicitly*:

  - Either: Use that number's `.ToString()` method; e.g. `(0x5555).ToString('D')`
  - Or: Use PowerShell's [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f); e.g. `'{0:D}' -f 0x5555`
  - Both approaches rely on *.NET numeric format strings*, either [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) ones.

Read on for **background information**:

---

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as many times before, has given the crucial pointer in a comment (and later helped improve this answer):

In [argument-parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode) - such as when invoking `Set-Variable` - **PowerShell parses an *unquoted literal argument* that *looks like* a number *as a number* and wraps it in a "half-transparent" [`[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) instance**, whose purpose is to *also* preserve the exact argument as specified *as a string*.

By *half-transparent* I mean that the resulting `$myVariable2`:

- **primarily is a *number*** - a regular (unwrapped) `[int]` instance - for the purpose of *calculations*; e.g., `$myVariable2 + 1` correctly returns `21846`

  - additionally, it shows that it is a number when you ask for its type with `.GetType()` or via the `Get-Member` cmdlet; in other words: in this case *PowerShell pretends that the wrapper isn't there* (see below for a workaround).
- **situationally behaves like a *string*** - returning the original argument literal exactly as specified - in the context of:

  - *output formatting*, both when printing directly to the console and generally with `Out-*` cmdlets such as `Out-File` (but not `Set-Content`) and `Format-*` cmdlets.
  - *string* formatting with [`-f`, PowerShell's format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) (which is based on .NET's [`String.Format()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format#Starting); e.g., `'The answer is {0}' -f 42` is equivalent to `[string]::Format('The answer is {0}', 42)`).
  - Surprisingly, it does *not* behave like a string inside an expandable string (`"$myVariable2"`) and when you call the `.ToString()` method (`$myVariable2.ToString()`) and (therefore also) with `Set-Content`.

    - However, the original string representation can be retrieved with `$myVariable2.psobject.ToString()`

Note that **specifying number literals as *command arguments* is inherently ambiguous**, because even *string* arguments generally don't need quoting (unless they contain special characters), so that, for instance, an argument such as `1.0` could be interpreted as a version *string* or as a floating-point *number*.

PowerShell's approach to resolving the ambiguity is to parse such a token *as a number*, which, however, situationally acts as a string<sup>[1]</sup>, as shown above.

The ambiguity can be avoided altogether by *typing parameters* so as to indicate whether an argument bound to it is a string or a number.

However, the `-Value` parameter of the `Set-Variable` and `New-Variable` cmdlets is - of necessity - `[object]` typed, because it must be able to accept values of any type, and these cmdlets don't have a parameter that would let you indicate the intended data type.

---

The solution is to **force the `-Value` argument to be treated as the *result of an expression* rather than as an *unquoted literal argument*, by enclosing it in `(...)`**:

```
# Due to enclosing in (...), the value that is stored in $myvariable2 
# is *not* wrapped in [psobject] and therefore behaves the same as
# $myvariable = 0x55555
Set-Variable -Name myvariable2 -Value (0x5555)
```

Conversely, if you don't apply the above solution, you have two choices for **unwrapping `$myvariable2`'s value on demand**:

```
# OK: $myvariable isn't wrapped in [psobject], so formatting it as a
#     hex. number works as expected:
PS> 'hex: 0x{0:x}' -f $myvariable
hex: 0x5555  # OK: Literal '0x' followed by hex. representation of the [int]

# !! Does NOT work as expected, because $myvariable2 is treated as a *string*
# !! That is, {0:x} is effectively treated as just {0}, and the string
# !! representation stored in the [psobject] wrapper is used as-is.   
PS> 'hex: 0x{0:x}' -f $myvariable2
hex: 0x0x5555  # !! Note the extra '0x'

# Workaround 1: Use a *cast* (with the same type) to force creation of
#               a new, *unwrapped* [int] instance:
PS> 'hex: 0x{0:x}' -f [int] $myvariable2
hex: 0x5555  # OK

# Workaround 2: Access the *wrapped* object via .psobject.BaseObject.
#               The result is an [int] that behaves as expected.
PS> 'hex: 0x{0:x}' -f $myvariable2.psobject.BaseObject
hex: 0x5555  # OK
```

Note: That `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), unexpectedly treats a `[psobject]`-wrapped number as a *string* is the subject of [GitHub issue #17199](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17199); sadly, the behavior was declared to be by design.

**Detecting a `[psobject]`-wrapped value:**

The simplest solution is to use `-is [psobject]`:

```
PS> $myvariable -is [psobject]
False  # NO wrapper object

PS> $myvariable2 -is [psobject]
True  # !! wrapper object
```

(PetSerAl offers the following, less obvious alternative:
`[Type]::GetTypeArray((, $myvariable2))`, which bypasses PowerShell's hiding-of-the-wrapper trickery.)

On a general note:

- `[psobject]` is generally meant to be an *invisible helper type*. While it provides *intentional* behavior modification in the case at hand, there are several scenarios in which its incidental use causes *undesired* variations in behavior: see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

---

[1] **Preserving the input string representation in implicitly typed numbers passed as command arguments**:

Unlike traditional shells, PowerShell uses rich types, so that an argument literal such as `01.2` is *instantly* parsed as a *number* - a `[double]` in this case, and if it were used as-is, it would result in a *different representation* on output, because - once parsed as a number - default output formatting is applied on output (where the number must again be turned into a *string*):

```
 PS> 01.2
 1.2  # !! representation differs (and is culture-sensitive)
```

However, the intent of the *target command* may ultimately be to treat the argument as a *string* and in that case you do *not* want the output representation to change.
(Note that while you *can* disambiguate numbers from strings by using *quoting* (`01.2` vs. `'01.2'`), this is not generally *required* in command arguments, the same way it isn't required in traditional shells.)

It is for that reason that a `[psobject]` wrapper is used to capture the original string representation and use it on output.

**Note: Arguably, a more consistent approach would have been to *always* treat unquoted literal arguments *as strings*, except when bound to explicitly numerically typed parameters in PowerShell commands.**

This is a necessity for invoking *external programs*, to which arguments can only ever be passed *as strings*.

That is, after initial parsing as a number, PowerShell must use *the original string representation* when building the command line (Windows) / passing the argument (Unix-like platforms) as part of the invocation of the external program.

If it didn't do that, arguments could inadvertently be changed, as shown above (in the example above, the external program would receive string `1.2` instead of the originally passed `01.2`).

You can also demonstrate the behavior using PowerShell code, with an *untyped* parameter - though note that is generally preferable to explicitly type your parameters:

```
 PS> & { param($foo) $foo.GetType().Name; $foo } -foo 01.2
 Double  # parsed as number - a [double]
 01.2    # !! original string representation, because $foo wasn't typed
```

- `$foo` is an *untyped* parameter, which means that the type that PowerShell *inferred* during initial parsing of literal `01.2` is used.
- Yet, given that the command (a script block (`{ ... }`) in this case) didn't declare a parameter *type* for `$foo`, the `[psobject]` wrapper that is implicitly used shows the original string representation *on output*.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is already answered by @PetSerAl in the comments. Your second question:

> How can I display format result like printf %d %x

Use PowerShell [string formatting](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to obtain the desired results.

Comment: @Enigmativity: @PetSerAl's comment is to-the-point, but esoteric, so including it as-is will likely not help much. Fortunately, there's already an answer that _builds on_ his comment and explains the underlying problem in detail. Also note that the question is about the difference between direct assignment (`=`) vs. a - seemingly equivalent - `Set-Variable` call. It isn't about _number formatting_ per se.