# When should I pick using a const over a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Based on what should I pick one of these ways to define a const/variable?

```
Set-Variable test -Option Constant -Value 100
```

and

```
$test = 100
```

Comment: Your answer is actually in a previous post located here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194805/whats-different-between-myvariable-and-set-variable-in-powershell

Comment: That was informative but it doesn't answer the question. Why would I pick one over the other?

Comment: the 2 commands above aren't the same. One sets a constant and the other sets a variable. Obviously most of the cases `$var = value` works but if you want more options then you have to use `Set-Variable`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I would like to define a var/const to be equal to 24. What are key factors to make me pick one over the other?

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate based on its _original_ title - I missed the `-Option Constant` angle. `$test = ...` invariably create a _read-write_ variable in the _current scope_ (which is visible to all descendant scopes). In order to set options such as `Constant` and to set variable in _ancestral_ scopes with `-Scope` (not recommended), you indeed need to use [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable)